# Bacon.js control buffering of stream with other stream

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

I want to buffer values of an EventStream in Bacon.js exactly like [`buffer(closingSelector)`](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer(rx.functions.Func0)) behaves in RxJava. When the "controller stream" (closingSelector in RxJava method) emits a new value, then the event buffer gets flushed.

So I want that the stream output is similar as in `stream.bufferWithTimeOrCount`, but instead of controlling buffering with time interval or event count I want to control buffering with other stream.

Is there an easy way to implement this in Bacon.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacon.js didn't have the function as you needed it, so I looked at the [bacon.js source](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/blob/master/dist/Bacon.js) and wrote a modified version of `holdWhen`.

```
Bacon.EventStream.prototype.bufferUntilValue = function(valve) {
var valve_ = valve.startWith(false);

  return this.filter(false).merge(valve_.flatMapConcat((function(_this) {
    return function() {
        return _this.scan([], (function(xs, x) {
            return xs.concat(x);
        }), {
            eager: true
        }).sampledBy(valve).take(1);
    };
  })(this)));
};
```

To see this in action, check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8uxk/).

Comment: Really nice approach! Cleaner than my solution (using `holdWhen` and `bufferWithTime` together). It took a while to understand how each valve event spawns a new "scanner" which returns the buffered values  with `sampledBy(valve).take(1)` when the following valve event arrives.

Comment: I simplified the solution, see it here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DeQy/)
(though later I noticed that you modified `holdWhen` only a little, so maybe there is a reason for `this.filter(false).merge(..)` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

`Bacon.holdWhen` available since about 0.7.14 does almost what you want, although buffered events are emitted one by one:

> stream.holdWhen(valve) pauses and buffers the event stream if last event in valve is truthy. All buffered events are released when valve becomes falsy.

If you need to emit buffered events as a single event, you can try something like the following:

```
// source streams
var sourceObservable = Bacon.interval(1000);
var closingSelector = new Bacon.Bus();

// Constructing a new Observable where we're going to keep our state.
// 
// We need to keep track of two things: 
//   - the buffer that is currently being filled, and
//   -  a previous buffer that is being flushed.
// The state will then look like this:
//   [ buffer, flushed]
// where both buffer and flushed is an array of events from the source observable.

// empty initial state
var initialState = {buffer: [], flushed: []}

// There are two operations on the state: appending a new element to the buffer 
// and flushing the current buffer:

// append each event from the source observable to the buffer,
// keeping flushed unchanged
var appends = sourceObservable.map(function(e) {
   return function(state) {
       state.buffer.push(e); return state; 
   } 
});

// each event from the closingSelector replaces the `flushed` with 
// the `buffer`'s contents, inserting an empty buffer.
var flushes = closingSelector.map(function(_) {
   return function(state) { return {buffer: [], flushed: state.buffer} }
})

// merge appends and flushes into a single stream and apply them to the initial state
var ops = appends.merge(flushes)
var state = ops.scan(initialState, function(acc, f) { return f(acc) });

// resulting stream of flushed events
var flushed = state.sampledBy(closingSelector).map(function(state) { return state.flushed })

// triggered with `closingSelector.push({})`
flushed.onValue(function(x) { console.log("flushed", x) })
```

Answer (score 0):

[`stream.holdWhen(valve)`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#stream-holdwhen) looks like almost exactly what you want. It works a little different than `buffer(closingSelector)`: instead of buffering all the time and flush buffer on event from `closingSelector`, it toggles buffering depend on last value in `value` stream.

Maybe you could use `holdWhen` as it is, but if you want behavior like in `buffer(closingSelector)`, you might do something like this:

```
var result = sourceStream.holdWhen(closingSelector.flatMap(function(){
  return Bacon.fromArray([false, true]);
}).toProperty(true));
```

On each event from `closingSelector` we generate two events in `value` stream with values `true` and `false`, i.e. turning off buffering (which triggers flush) and then immediately turning it back on.

Comment: Actually my initial solution was very similar, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRWJf/). Only difference is that because I wanted the output as array of values, I collected them with `bufferWithTime(1)`. It does its job but I thought that there must be a better solution :)